# Reordering forested model variables in sjPlot with plot_models (r)

Tags: r, sjplot

I have a group of models that I am plotting together in R using the `plot_models` function from the `sjPlot` package. The models are plotting confidence intervals for similar `felm` regressions that use different datasets. All the models share the same variables of interest, and their confidence intervals occupy the same ranges. I have successly plotted all of the models, however, I now cannot order them how would be ideal.

My code is the following:

```
placebo_models <- paste0("outcome", 1:13, " ~ Variable1 + Variable2 | fe_variable |0| fe_variable") |> lapply(\(x) felm(as.formula(x), data = df))


models_list <- list(placebo_models[[13]], placebo_models[[12]], placebo_models[[11]], placebo_models[[10]], placebo_models[[9]], placebo_models[[8]], placebo_models[[7]], placebo_models[[6]], placebo_models[[5]], placebo_models[[4]], placebo_models[[3]], placebo_models[[2]], placebo_models[[1]])
                  
testplot <- plot_models(models_list, colors = c("RED"), show.values = TRUE, p.threshold = 0.05, spacing = 0.8, dot.size = 1, digits = 5, title = "Placebo Models", axis.labels = c("Variable1", "Variable2")) + scale_color_discrete(labels = c("m1", "m2", "m3", "m4", "m5", "m6", "m7", "m8", "m9", "m10", "m11", "m12", "m13"))
```

My current plot output is the following:

[image: Plot]

Ideally, I would like to change this model to report in order (descending from the top) m1's Variable 1 confidence interval, followed by m1's Variable 2 confidence interval, before going to m2 (Variable1, then Variable2), m3 (Variable1, then Variable2), etc.

Is there a way to reorder the plotted lines such that this is possible? The variables are identical across all the models, so it should fit, as long as it can be restructured. Can the variables of different models be reordered and inter-mixed within the same plot like so?

I am unfortunately not able to share the original data, but this visualization should explain the problem. Many thanks!

Comment: Options for sorting estimates within sjPlot are described in https://strengejacke.github.io/sjPlot/articles/plot_model_estimates.html#sorting-estimates. Does adding `order.terms = c(26:1)` to `plot_models()` solve your problem?

Comment: @jared_mamrot Thank you for this. No, unfortunately ```order.terms``` does not appear to exist. Was it removed/ was the package updated? I tried it and the function is not recognized at all. Perhaps there is an alternative?

Comment: @jared_mamrot Yes, it produces: ```Warning: Could not access model information.Error in if (fam.info$is_linear) tf <- NULL else tf <- "exp" : 
  argument is of length zero``` It seems that syntax only exists in the ```plot_model``` function. Is there another way to do this, or perhaps a way to alter the GG object after it's already created?

Comment: Ahh! Sorry - that's not implemented yet (it's a requested feature: https://github.com/strengejacke/sjPlot/issues/452). Hopefully someone else has a solution. Sorry I couldn't be more help

Comment: @jared_mamrot No worries at all! Thank you for trying. I hope the package creator may add that functionality in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order in which elements appear in your legend is based on the order you feed them to `plot_models`. The order in which the y-axis appears is the order in which they are placed in your first model.

Check it out. This is the example published by `sjPlot::plot_models()`. First, as it's presented in help, then how you can change the order of the legend items or the plotted items. As for the y-axis, the ability to rearrange it may be impacted by your model. You can rearrange the order in which you call the independent variables in many regression models without changing the results. I run a few checks here to show that this `lm` is not impacted by variable order.

```
library(sjPlot)

data(efc)

# fit three models
fit1 <- lm(barthtot ~ c160age + c12hour + c161sex + c172code, 
           data = efc)
fit2 <- lm(neg_c_7 ~ c160age + c12hour + c161sex + c172code, 
           data = efc)
fit3 <- lm(tot_sc_e ~ c160age + c12hour + c161sex + c172code, 
           data = efc)

# plot multiple models
plot_models(fit1, fit2, fit3, grid = TRUE)

# plot multiple models with legend labels and
# point shapes instead of value labels
plot_models(
  fit1, fit2, fit3,
  axis.labels = c(
    "Carer's Age", "Hours of Care", "Carer's Sex", 
    "Educational Status"
  ),
  m.labels = c("Barthel Index", "Negative Impact", 
               "Services used"),
  show.values = FALSE, show.p = FALSE, p.shape = TRUE
)
```

[image]

If I wanted to rearrange the legend `Dependent Variables`, I need to reorder the plots in the call. So I'll reference the model order. The labels need to be in the same order as the plots.

```
plot_models(
      fit3, fit2, fit1,
      axis.labels = c(
        "Carer's Age", "Hours of Care", "Carer's Sex", 
        "Educational Status"
      ),
      m.labels = rev("Barthel Index", "Negative Impact", 
                   "Services used"),
      show.values = FALSE, show.p = FALSE, p.shape = TRUE
    )
```

[image]

Next, I've rearranged the call for `fit1` and returned to the original plotting order, you'll see that this plot has a different order on the y-axis, but the legend matches the legend in the first plot.

```
fit1a <- lm(barthtot ~ c172code + c161sex + c12hour + c160age, 
           data = efc)
plot_models(
  fit1a, fit2, fit3,
  axis.labels = rev(c(
    "Carer's Age", "Hours of Care", "Carer's Sex", 
    "Educational Status")),
  m.labels = c("Barthel Index", "Negative Impact", 
               "Services used"),
  show.values = FALSE, show.p = FALSE, p.shape = TRUE
)

# validate models are identical with R2 and Fstat
summary(fit1)[[8]] # [1] 0.2695598 
summary(fit1a)[[8]] # [1] 0.2695598 

summary(fit1)[[10]][1] # value # 75.28364  
summary(fit1a)[[10]][1] # value # 75.28364
```

[image]